# How to write to text file python 3?

Tags: python

How to write to text file python 3?

I want to read each line and write to outputDoc1.txt for line1 ,  outputDoc2.txt for line1, outputDoc3.txt for line1

```
line1 = "Alright, I think I understand. Thank you again"
line2 = " just had to use join to separate the data"
line3 = " whether that's desirable or not I suppose is down to the OP"
path = "C:\\Users\\subashini.u\\Desktop\\"

l=["line1","line2","line3"]
count = 0
for txt_file in l:
    count += 1
    for x in range(count):
        with open(path + "outputDoc%s.txt" % x) as output_file:
            output_file.write(txt_file)
            #shutil.copyfileobj(file_response.raw, output_file)
            output_file.close()
```

Comment: Why are you closing the file a) after you write a single line, and b) at all?  The `with` expression will close the file for you.

Comment: Is there a reason where you need to write one line at a time to each file? Because right now you'll do line1, line1, line1, line2, etc. If that's not required then I would recommend writing all of the lines at once to each file so you're not reopening the files every time a new line needs to be written.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line1 = "Alright, I think I understand. Thank you again"
line2 = " just had to use join to separate the data"
line3 = " whether that's desirable or not I suppose is down to the OP"
path = "D://foldername/"

ls=[line1,line2,line3]

for i, l in enumerate(ls, start=1):
    with open(path + "outputDoc%s.txt" % i, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the `write` attribute in file open and referring to string and not line elements:

just change

loop to:

```py
l=[line1,line2,line3]
count = 0
for txt_file in l:
    print(txt_file)
    count += 1
    with open(path + "outputDoc%s.txt" % count, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(txt_file + '\n')
```

it writes:

line1 in `<path>/outputDoc1.txt`

line2 in `<path>/outputDoc2.txt`

etc

Comment: as u said it just write line 3 to all file

Comment: because you are using a range loop that goes until the last element in list for loop, try as I edited

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you currently don't write the lines you want.

Change

```
l=["line1","line2","line3"]
```

to

```
l = [line1, line2, line3]
```

Then, to make things a bit easier, you could do something like this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(l, start=1):
    ...
```

To open the file and write something, you need to open it with the correct `mode` -> 'write'. The default mode with `open()` is `read`, therefore you currently can't write to the file.

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    ...
    # no f.close() needed here
```